# What is the motivation for all advanced intelligent extraterrestrial alien races to mask their presence from the primitive human?

Tags: technology, aliens, communication

There are things that exists in the world which cannot be explained or proved nor disproved, numerous UFO sightings caught on tapes or stories retold by many eyewitnesses over the past decades seem to suggest there are more to it than meets the eye.

Perhaps all aliens prefer to remain anonymous and want nothing to do with us, assuming we are not alone why would the E.T. hide from us when we obviously don't and can't bite? I'm looking for answer that suggest it is in their best interest to ignore us entirely maybe occasional but unintentional hiccups like the WOW signal.

Comment: They are just following The Prime Directive.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Directive

Comment: In short, we're fickle, ignorant, socially awkward and power-mongering. Need more be said?

Comment: As it stands, this question is primarily opinion-based, there is no way to objectively judge different answers.

Answer (score 4):

**ARCHIVE: LIFE-FORM: HUMAN: OVERVIEW_ ... ~(Translation in progress, please wait).**

"Humans are odd creatures. Odd, but tasty..." Quarg, The Destroyer (13.24.1224.1).

**Social Tendencies:**

_Apex in their environment, Humans construct intricate nests out of synthetic materials, grouping in vast numbers to form dense colonies where they raise their young. Despite nesting in such close proximity to one another, they tend to keep to themselves and rarely socialise with others nearby unless having an adequate reason for doing so. Instead, they take to using a metaphysical communications array called "The Internet" as a means to interact with like-minded individuals, or to simply procrastinate whilst working.

¬

¬
**SEARCH .... ENTER KEY WORDS: _ "Interacting With Humans"**

¬
......Searching...................... // : 1 Result Found.

¬

### **WARNING!**

_Humans are unpredictable creatures, possessing short tempers and a fear for things they do not fully understand. They exert full authority over their environment, destroying any habitat that comes between them and the construction of new nest sites and dislike opposition.

_They are known to frequently harm or kill their own kind unprovoked, marginalising those who are classed as "different" from the colonies majority are not known for their compassion toward extra-terrestrial beings, such thoroughly explored via a section of the human video-archive labelled "Science Fiction". 
Humans also possess a vast arsenal of powerful weapons and are renowned for using them to exert dominance over their rivals/"lesser beings", or in a bid to protect what they feel is under-threat. Their lust for power and control in their small world is beyond reason.

**ADVISORY INFORMATION:** Humans take a long time to build trust, frequently questioning their current social relations with others. They are easily insulted and become violent if aggravated or feel at a disadvantage. They are best left alone; the concealment of species presence should remain a top priority when around EARTH - the less Humans know of life outside their bubble, the better off the rest of the galaxy will be.

"Odd Creatures Humans, they don't like to be followed after dark and dislike probing of any sort. Frankly, I'd rather the company of an *Garoosian Death Beast* than a human being..." Quarg, The Destroyer (34.1566.3.22)

**EXTREME CAUTION IS ADVISED.**

Comment: Yes, when you look at it this way: we don't seem all that friendly, do we?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite difficult to hide from another sufficiently advanced civilization at all. Radiowave emissions, any form of energy emissions can hardly be hidden from a curious explorer. Like we are. So hiding their civ from our view will be a hard and daunting task. They will have to go to great lengths so they need a strong motivation.

(Sidenote: FTL travel might reduce the efford required to hide from us by a lot - if their civilization is younger than the distance between their worlds and ours, we cannot detect them, because any form of information travels slower than light, so they are absolutely safe until a certain point in the future.)

About the don't and can't bite thing... we DO bite. We kill each other all the time, and we are omnivorous predators. We kill other animals to feed upon them. And hell yes, we can bite them. If we knew where they were coming from, we could always throw a piece of rock (asteroid) at their home world. Takes a few hundred or more years to arrive, but once it arrives... it is very difficult to properly secure your worlds against an intelligent race. Life is too fragile when compared to the distances, conditions and energies in space. And of course a civilization needs to keep in mind: if they have contact with us, sooner or later we will steal, cheat, espionage or trade or otherwise get our hands on an FTL drive / advanced alien tech they don't want us to have. We will. Just a matter of time. And then we have ftl-traveling spacefaring omnivorous predators...

Now, to their motivation.

I think, keeping the above in mind, there are several basic emotions that can cause them to keep secret:

- Responsibility: Our aliens know, maybe from past experience, that contacting a low-tech civ can cause economic problems, culture shock, panic, wars, destabilization or even the downfall of the primitive civ. They want to avoid this, and mask themselves to protect us.
- Fear: There are a lot of reasons to fear us. Maybe we are - on a galactic scale - a fast growing, super aggressive race. Or the last species they met instantly went to war with them. Or they are herbivorous, and consider all creatures that eat other creatures as dangerous. Always. Just to be safe. Of course they don't fear us NOW. But they fear what we might BECOME, if we got our paws on advanced tech. Or maybe we just repopulate soooo fast that they want to wait a few hundred years, so they can secure the best planets in our neighbourhood?
- Curiosity: They are just super curious and want to see how we develop without aid and help.
- They need help: I like the following scenario. Their civ is super old. And super advanced. Sadly, in the last 10.000 years, they haven't made any scientific progress. Moreso, they became aware that their civ is in a deadlock. If the current development goes on, the economical, biological or some other cultural problem will eventually kill their race. Not now, but in a few thousand years. From their point of view, science is at it's end. All possible theories have been postulated, all inventions that are possible have been made. Then they found us. We are super behind in technology, but they found something on earth that they never thought of. It might be something insignificant. Like... music. The species is deaf, so they never thought about it. While this doesn't solve their problems, it proves something: humans can invent things they haven't. So science is NOT at it's end, just THEIR sience is. So they watch over us, protect us from danger, keep all other races away and watch the hell out that we don't discover them, because if we DID, we might get influenced by their tech and their way of thinking, leading us into the same deadlock. And they watch over us, hoping that one day we will invent something to help them out of their troubles.